# How can I turn off retweets from users in Tweetdeck?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

I know that I can turn off retweets showing in Twitter itself ([here's a guide for it](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-mute-retweets-from-any-user-on-twitter-1443476417)), but even though I turn off retweets from a specific user on Twitter, they still show up in tweetdeck. Does anyone know how to turn off retweets from specific users there as well? I have searched around, but only found other people trying to figure the same thing out (ex [#1](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1105709-tweetdeck-and-retweets/), [#2](https://twitter.com/imn0taaron/status/471799957155225600)).

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could find to a real solution is to create a column that has retweets disabled:
[image]

Of course, the downside is you now need to maintain two lists potentially (if you want retweets from some sources, and not for others) for each of your original lists.

Comment: Where is this screenshot from? Thanks!